# Compare two Lists of Objects List A & B and store in another List C in dart

Tags: arrays, list, object, dart

I am trying to compare two lists, **allCategories** and **selecetdCategories**, whereby if there are similar items in List **selecetdCategories** and **allCategories** , I should first store the existing ones first in the List **orderPreferences**, then afterwards , I append the non-existing ones. I actually made some research on existing questions on StackOverflow but I couldn't connect the dots.

Forexample , each list has the following items:

`allCategories :`

- Agriculture
- Opinions
- Education
- Tourism
- Education
- Culture

`selecetdCategories :`

- Agriculture
- Education
- Tourism

**Then this is what I expect to have in the *`orderPreferences`* List** items should first insert the `selectedCategories` list item then later add the non-existing ones, eg :

- Agriculture
- Education
- Tourism
- Opinions
- Education
- Culture

Below is my current code :

```
class Model {
  int id;
  String name;

  Model({this.name, this.id});
}

void main() {
  List<Model> allCategories = List();
  allCategories.add(Model(id: 1, name: 'Agriculture'));
  allCategories.add(Model(id: 2, name: 'Opinions'));
  allCategories.add(Model(id: 3, name: 'Education'));
  allCategories.add(Model(id: 4, name: 'Tourism'));
  allCategories.add(Model(id: 5, name: 'Education'));
  allCategories.add(Model(id: 6, name: 'Culture'));

  List<Model> selecetdCategories = List();
  selecetdCategories.add(Model(id: 1, name: 'Agriculture'));
  selecetdCategories.add(Model(id: 5, name: 'Education'));
  selecetdCategories.add(Model(id: 4, name: 'Tourism'));

  List<Model> orderPreferences = List();

  for (var i = 0; i < allCategories.length; i++) {
    if (allCategories.contains(Model(
        id: selecetdCategories[i].id, name: selecetdCategories[i].name))) {
      orderPreferences
          .add(Model(id: allCategories[i].id, name: allCategories[i].name));
    }
    orderPreferences
        .add(Model(id: allCategories[i].id, name: allCategories[i].name));
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < orderPreferences.length; i++) {
    print(' name : ${orderPreferences[i].name}');
  }
}
```

But, I am getting an exception when am running it :

```
 Uncaught Error: RangeError (index): Index out of range: index should
 be less than 3: 3
```

What could be the solution to compare the 2 lists of Objects in dart ?

Comment: How about using map.  allCategoriesMap  and selecetdCategoriesMap as u have the ids.

then iterate the smallest map and peek its value in another map,
store it in result and delete the entry from both the maps. 

U can then push all the leftovers from both maps to the resultList

Comment: @pranavprashant, how can I do the deletion, you talked about, am still confused  :\, it would be welcomed with an answer please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of possible solutions to your example:

```
List allWithoutSelected = allCategories.where((item) => !selectedCategories.contains(item)).toList();   

List finalList = selectedCategories + allWithoutSelected;
```

What I did here is first filter the models which are not selected and then concatenate selectedCategories list with allWithoutSelected. This way the order is correct and also there are no duplicates.

For the `contains` method to work, you need to override compare operator in your  model or make it extend to Equatable: https://pub.dev/packages/equatable

Comment: Thanks for the answer, its actually close to what I want, however surprisingly there are duplicates, I think we have to use a set on `allWithoutSelected`

Comment: Tried to use this `finalList.toSet().toList();`, but no luck , it still shows duplicates.

Comment: Man thanks a bunch, I had missed adding Equatable, thought it was an alternative , I added and everything worked well. Thanks man